# Post tweet without going to twitter site in browser?

Tags: java, twitter

Is there a direct way to post a tweet on twitter ? I was trying an application that lets you tweet from your desktop. By know when the user presses  the button in the application ,the default browser takes him to `www.twitter.com/share` and then again the person has to press the tweet button. Is there any way that lets me tweet directly by just pressing a tweet button   so that the application has some significance ! ? *(once)*

I am trying this thing in java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.jsp).